# Mailchimp on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, mailchimp

I want to use MailChimp on Magento 2 . for use in the footer for a subscriber and in a popup. So there are two ways on internet  1 is using through GitHub and 2nd installing from admin side . which is better?

> https://github.com/mailchimp/mc-magento2

or

> https://marketplace.magento.com/mailchimp-mc-magento2.html

And how I will connect it to footer and popup?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend you to install it with composer since it will be easier to update it. If you have SSH access (command line access) just use the command

> composer require mailchimp/mc-magento2

in your Magento root directory.

And next of course do a

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Now if you ever do the command `composer update` it will automatically update your MailChimp also.

**Edit:**

Your website has a newsletter subscription standard. I believe that MailChimp will use that to sync with their API. So its bound as default. You do not have to bind it to anything specially as long as your customers appear in **Marketing->Communications->Newsletter Subscribers**

Comment: thank you brother. and how to join it with email popup and footer where subscriber subscribe for email ?

Comment: Look at my edit.

Comment: So I dont need to do anything right ? let me try to install first then.

Comment: As long as your subscribers are getting inside the newsletter subscriptions no

Comment: its asking for   "API Key list"  from where to get this ?

Comment: You need to get this from Mailchimp somewhere

Comment: https://kb.mailchimp.com/integrations/e-commerce/connect-or-disconnect-mailchimp-for-magento-2

Comment: I am getting coloum of mailchimp here but not logo like this or integrated form  https://marketplace.magento.com/media/catalog/product/cache/image/750x360/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe/o/r/orders_7_1_1_2.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69049/discussion-between-swat-be-and-learner).

Comment: I need a small help bro

Comment: Sorry currently in a big project with a fast deadline. But question to how to set things up its best to ask someone from mailchimp. They will help you

Comment: @CompactCode, can we install extension and its library without composer? I would like to install by placing module in app/code, but where can we place the library files?

Comment: Yes you can. Not sure why you want to do that though. Its a different question how you need to do that so i suggest opening a new questions