# Magento 2 how to install Mailchimp

Tags: magento2, mailchimp

I'm using Magento 2.3.3 and I'm not able to install mailchimp. The documentation doesn't seem to be very clear...
I'm not entierly sure about my folder path since I cannot find any documentation about it.

I've set up:

```
/var/www/html/root/app/code/mailchimp/mc-magento2
```

and

```
/var/www/html/root/app/code/ebizmarts/mailchimp-lib
```

With all their specific files downloaded from Magento marketplace.

I've tried the commands:

```
composer require ebizmarts/mailchimp-lib
composer require mailchimp/mc-magento2:102.3.42
```

But I always get the error

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                       
  Could not find a matching version of package ebizmarts/mailchimp-lib. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and t  
  hat the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (alpha).
```

So im guessing that It's something about my folder path but I cannot find any information about it. Anyone got any clue? Thanks

What I have checked:

- [Magento 2.2.8: cannot install MailChimp](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293200/magento-2-2-8-cannot-install-mailchimp)
- [Mailchimp on Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202488/mailchimp-on-magento-2)
- [How to install Mailchimp in magento 2.1.5 from composer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/309782/how-to-install-mailchimp-in-magento-2-1-5-from-composer)
- http://wiki.ebizmarts.com/installation-guide-m4m2
- https://github.com/mailchimp/mc-magento2/releases
- List item

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using wrong installation command.

** You don't need to download and put module files manually to app/code/.....
And if you already have module files for mailchimp, remove them first.

Run this command on your **magento2 root folder**.

```
composer require mailchimp/mc-magento2
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but I get the error:


Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - mailchimp/mc-magento2 102.3.42 requires ebizmarts/mailchimp-lib >=3.0.27 -> no matching package found.

Comment: is same problem, how i can fix this?